# Animating left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve something that seems quite simple but I have hard time doing so.

How can I animate a div making its width 80% of original from left to right? 
I want to keep the right margin where it is and moving the left one toward right.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Hello Joseph. I tried using animate is several ways. It is basically several hours I'm playing around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `float: right` on your element. Then:

```
$("#animate").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: $(this).width() * .8 }); 
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzgZ6/)

Answer (score 1):

primatology was faster, but here's my jsFiddle anyways as it adds some right margin: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4EF6h/).